# How to run Webharvest on Google App engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-scraping, webharvest

I have developed a **scraper** with web harvest(http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/). However, I want to let the program run on a server. Is it possible to run this system on google app engine? Thx for your replies!